# Lines & Planes - Determine the distance between lines

Tags: vectors

Determine the distance between the line $$(x,y,z) = (4,5,-2) + t(1,1,-1), \qquad t\in\mathbb{R}$$ and the plane $$(x,y,z) = (2,4,3)+s(3,2,0)+t(1,0,2),\qquad s,t\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Comment: I said shortest distance because there is no unique way of getting from a point on the line to a point on the plane. And even if you specify it as the shortest distance from any point on the line to the plane, that distance could vary along the line. Here the shortest distance is constant because the direction of the line is perpendicular to a normal of the plane. What have you tried in order to find the distance?

Comment: For the record. The OP has flagged the question asking for its deletion, because *they gave me the answers simply and didn't teach me anything*. Some of the answers here have upvotes, so I am a bit reluctant to grant the wish (as a matter of policy). Do take that into account, if so inclined. Mathunan Sup, it would make things easier for others, if you explained it in the question body that you only want hints and teaching. You phrased the question like a teacher assigning homework would so people will think that you just want this done. That is guaranteed way to attract negative attention.

Answer (score 1):

The line is parallel to the plane since 
$$ (1,1,-1) = \frac{1}{2}(3,2,0)-\frac{1}{2}(1,0,2), $$
hence it is enough to compute the distance of $(4,5,-2)-(2,4,3)=(2,1,-5)$ from the plane $\pi=\text{Span}\left((3,2,0),(1,0,2)\right)$. A possible approach is to find an orthonormal base of $\pi$, complete it to an orthonormal base of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and represent $(2,1,-5)$ with respect to such a base. An equivalent approach is to find the minimum of

$$ \left\|(2,1,-5)-s(3,2,0)-t(1,0,2)\right\|^2 = 30-16 s+13 s^2+16 t+6 s t+5 t^2 $$
by annihilating the partial derivatives and finding $s=\frac{8}{7},t=-\frac{16}{7}$.

It follows that the wanted distance is $\color{red}{\large\sqrt{\frac{18}{7}}}$.

Comment: Homework questions should be **not** answered in such detail, or else the questioner will never learn how to do these exercises him/herself.

Comment: Our 2 results are in agreement. It's 2 different ways to solve the problem. There would be a third way : select a line in the plane, for example $(x,y,z) = (2,4,3)+s(3,2,0)$ and use the formula for the shortest distance between 2 straight lines $P_k+t\vec{v_k}$, i.e., $D=\dfrac{\vec{P_1P_2} . \vec{n}}{\|\vec{n}\|}$ with $\vec{n}:=\vec{v_1} \times \vec{v_2}$ as given for example in [here](pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/251/distance.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Since this is most certainly homework, I'll just give a *HINT* :

If the line and the plane are not parallel their distance is $0$ because they meet in one point.

If they are parallel to compute their distance you may just compute the distance from *any* point on the line to the plane. For this there's a formula (that you should know or be able to find in your notes/textbook) once the plane is given in the cartesian form $ax+by+cz+d=0$.

To test whether the line and the plane are perpendicular, just check the orthogonality between the direction perpendicular to the plane and that of the line.

Comment: @MathunanSup: what I described in my answer **is** a step-by-step procedure. Or are you posting here hoping someone solves your homework?

Answer (score 0):

The cross product of the two vectors $(3,2,0)$ and $(1,0,2)$ gives a normal vector  $N(4,-6,-2)$ to plane $(\Pi)$. The dot product of $N$ with the directing vector of the straight line : $(1,1,-1)$ is 0 ; thus we have checked that the straight line and the plane are parallel.

It suffices now to compute the distance from any point, e.g., $P_0(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(4,5,-2)$ of the line to the plane $(\Pi)$ using the formula given in [this reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-PlaneDistance.html):

$$d((P_0),(\Pi))=\dfrac{|a x_0+b y_0+c z_0+d|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \ \ (1)$$

if the plane has **cartesian equation** $ax+by+cz+d=0$.

But this cartesian equation is very easy to obtain because we have the normal vector $N$ : it is $4x-6y-2z+d=0$ with $d$ easily computed by forcing (2,4,3) to belong to this plane, yielding the following cartesian equation of the plane:

$$4x-6y-2z+22=0$$

It suffices now to plug values $a=4, b=-6, c=-2, d=22$ in (1) to obtain the result... up to you...

Comment: Homework questions should be not answered in such detail, or else the questioner will never learn how to do these exercises him/herself.

Comment: Now that I have a larger experience of the huge variety of people asking questions on this site, I consider that a newcomer (as is the case here) doesn't know the rules of the game, I consider favorably his request as if he had already worked on the question (which we may suppose is the case at University undergraduate level as this is the case here). I am more severe for youngsters in high school that often want their homework to be done without effort.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thks.